# XSSFWorkbook takes lot time to load a excel (.xlsx) file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using following code in my program

```
FileInputStream fileFile = null;
try {
fileFile = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\work\\result\\n01jfvjnjn.xlsx"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
XSSFWorkbook workbookFile = null;
try {
workbookFile = new XSSFWorkbook(fileFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
XSSFSheet sheetFile = workbookFile.getSheet("Sheet1");
```

this xlsx file has 20 sheets and each sheet has 100 rows , its some what of 5mb file . I just go to specific sheet and print the first row and first column value it takes nearly 30 secs . 
much time taken in the XSSFWorkbook line . I allocated 3gb of heap and i tried below code no difference .

```
File file = new File("C:\\D\\Data Book.xlsx");
OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(file);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);
```

is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: Have you tried following the steps in the [POI FAQ entry on memory use](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10109)? Those steps are likely to help you narrow down the cause for speed too

Comment: try opening in readonly if you dont intend on writing:     OPCPackage.open(xlsxFile.getPath(), PackageAccess.READ);

Comment: Hi , I tried with SSPerformanceTest program with XSSF workbook, 50,000 rows and 50 columns initially i get outofmemory error then i increased heap size to 6gb after it executed but takes 88 seconds to complete it . In that document it says "If you can't run that with 50,000 rows and 50 columns in all of HSSF, XSSF and SXSSF in under 3 seconds (ideally a lot less!), the problem is with your environment." i have allocated enough heap size then what should be the problem ?

Answer (score -1):

Heres a link to a number of classes, handling the big Xlsx problem in a few steps. You only need to handle the Array[String]'s you get from it and put them in a list of String Arrays.

Link: http://lchenaction.blogspot.nl/2013/12/how-to-read-super-large-excel-and-csv.html

Comment: The problem is not to read big files. In this case, a small file is taking too long to be loaded.